# NodeJS not passing object key-value pairs to MongoDB via Postman

Tags: node.js, mongodb, postman

I'm new to MongoDB and already feel the frustration that comes along when working with it [on Windows]. My problem is that I'm creating a USER object via POSTMAN.

Here's my **server.js** code for POSTing a user to MongoDB. 
P.S. Also Sublime is highlighting only the **.name**, but NOT **.username and .password.**

```
apiRouter.route('/users')

    // create a user (accessed at POST http://localhost:8080/users)
    .post(function(req, res) {

        var user = new User();      // create a new instance of the User model
        user.name = req.body.name;  // set the users name (comes from the request)
        user.username = req.body.username;  // set the users username (comes from the request)
        user.password = req.body.password;  // set the users password (comes from the request)

        user.save(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                // duplicate entry
                if (err.code == 11000) 
                    return res.json({ success: false, message: 'A user with that username already exists. '});
                else 
                    return res.send(err);
            }

            // return a message
            res.json({ message: 'User created!' });
        });

    })
```

Maybe I do not know some caveats. Thanks.

Comment: What error do you get from postman?

Comment: @inspired None. It spits out the success message - User created. From the passed Params only .username gets added.

Comment: I'm sorry what is your error? if you
 `console.log(req.body.username,req.body.password);`

before you save do you get the correct values in the console?

Comment: @inspired The console shows the correct credentials. Also, trying to update a user shows me his username and password. Here's a new screenshot - http://take.ms/sKCQV . But the JSON response does not include his pass.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you are connecting to your mongoDB instance after your request parameter parsing.

for example:

```
//parse request parameters

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//connect to MongoDB

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017');
```